# Test an application using LDAP

Tags: testing, ldap

I am in the preparation phase of testing an application that will be using LDAP for user authentication. What are some tips or advice you might have for this endeavor?

I don't have a great understanding of LDAP but I believe all that will be used is the application client calls to LDAP with a username and sees if the password matches. Is that an accurate description? Also, what are some edge cases to test? Thanks.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, do not forget to check for response controls in responses from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDAP authentication is often (but not always) a 2-step process: first the application does an LDAP query to locate the "distinguished name" (dn) of the account the user's trying to authenticate to, then it tries to log in ("bind", in LDAP parlance) as that dn, using the user-supplied password.

If the "bind" attempt works, the application knows the password is correct. (The LDAP server is likely not configured to allow the application to actually extract the password and do the comparison itself, for obvious security reasons).

An LDAP-enabled application will typically require a way to configure:

- hostname/port of LDAP server
- search base (e.g., dc=mycompany,dc=org)
- user search filter (e.g. "(|(cn=%userid)(mail=%userid))")
- application credentials for the initial LDAP query (unless the server allows anonymous queries)

You will most likely need to support SSL, so you don't send the user's password to the LDAP server in cleartext.

Answer (score 1):

This strongly depends on your technology.

If you are directly querying the ldap you have to care about performance e.g. how fast are your queries, how often you have to do them and if you server is sized appropriately.

If you are using some kind of container that it providing SSO then these will usually have some caching features, etc.. There you have to check if everything is working properly.

Comment: I would also add that not all LDAP servers behave the same way. Active DIrectory, for example, does things differently than "normal" LDAP servers.

Answer (score 0):

You would need ldap_connect and ldap_bind functions. Also once you are binded with the ldap server you can search for entries on the ldap and get the user information.

Answer (score 0):

You should surely check if encodings are handled properly (try umlauts or other weird stuff in passwords).

And take care to test with the LDAP servers you care about, Active Directory, OpenLdap, Apaches LDAP Server, and a few others, they might show different behaviours.

Also check if the client handles 'referrals' correct, e.g. when you try to lookup users in a different domain (e.g. two AD forrests with forrest trust installed).